# curl gnutls_handshake failed TLS connection was non-properly terminated

Tags: rest, api, curl

I would like to get the info from my custom Haystack service with the command
`curl -v -X GET https://<myIP>:8443/api/haystack/about` and it fails, the following is the log from above command

```
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, GET is already inferred.
*   Trying <myproxy-ip>...
* Connected to proxy.example.com (myproxy-ip) port 911 (#0)
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to <myIP>:8443
> CONNECT <myIP>:8443 HTTP/1.1
> Host: <myIP>:8443
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
<
* Proxy replied OK to CONNECT request
* found 148 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 597 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* gnutls_handshake() failed: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) gnutls_handshake() failed: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
```

At the same time, the Haystack service is having a front end web portal, when I access with Chrome, I can see the warning `Privacy Error` and `NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`, but i still can proceed on the browser. I guess this might be the reason causing my `curl` fail.

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: these kinds of errors are almost always caused by using old bugged versions of curl/tls libs, what does `curl --version` output?

Comment: @hanshenrik `curl 7.47.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.47.0 GnuTLS/3.4.10 zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.32 librtmp/2.3`

Comment: that's an early (january) 2016 version.. there's a good chance your problem would go away if you just updated curl & GnuTLS

Comment: @hanshenrik updated curl to `7.62.0` and it gives another error `curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to <myIP>:<port>`

Comment: what does `curl --version` say now?

Comment: @hanshenrik `curl 7.62.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.62.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2g zlib/1.2.8`

Comment: hate to say this, but your openssl-lib is an early 2016 version, `openssl 1.0.2g` was released in 1st march 2016, try updating your openssl lib. (if you already know how to compile curl from scratch, then compiling openssl from scratch is not difficult, and add your custom compiled openssl into curl with `./configure --with-ssl=/path/to/your/openssl`

Comment: I ran into the same error, and it was because I had supplied bad password with `-u` flag. Make sure the URL and any login is correct. I'm using curl v7.72.0 and GnuTLS v3.6.14. Even though this post is almost 4 years old, it's still the top hit for: "gnutls_handshake() failed: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated."